# How can I remove line breaks from a cell but keep the address format in the same cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

The cell I'm trying to remove line breaks from is this:

```
(Blank line break)
Test Company
1640 Test Avenue,
New York, NY 10035
(000)123-456    
(Blank line break)
```

I want to remove the two rows that have line breaks. Ive tried to use find and replace to replace the line breaks with alt code 0010 but it creates a long string.

I want to end up with this:

```
Test Company
1640 Test Avenue,
New York, NY 10035
(000)123-456
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I want to remove every blank line from the cell

Comment: Check the first character in the cell, if it's a carriage returns, remove it, if not, then leave things as they are. Do the same for the last character. If you have blank lines between two lines of text, look for two carriage returns in a row and change them for a single one

Comment: `MID$(Trim(Range("A1")),2,LEN(Trim(Range("A1")))-2)`

Comment: For extra lines in the middle of the text: `cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
Dim v
v = Trim(cell.Value)
if left(v,1)=vblf then v = right(v, len(v)-1)  'remove leading break
if right(v,1)=vblf then v = left(v, len(v)-1)  'remove trailingbreak
v = replace(v, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)              'remove blank lines
cell.value=v
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF that works similar to the worksheet TRIM function, but allows you to specify the character to trim:

```
Option Explicit
Function trimCHAR(ByVal S As String, char As String)
  Dim RE As Object
  Dim I As Long

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True

'need to do separately, otherwise multiple chars within will
'be removed
        .Pattern = char & "$"
        S = .Replace(S, "") 'Remove extra chars within or at end of string
        .Pattern = "^" & char
        S = .Replace(S, "") 'Remove extra chars at start of string
End With
trimCHAR = S
End Function
```

In your situation, you could use it like:

```
=trimCHAR(cell_ref,CHAR(10))
```

OR you could use it as part of a macro that iterates through all the cells to be processed.

The idea for this came from Power Query's `Text.Trim` function which only works on the beginning and end of the string, but allows any character string to be specified; along with an adaptation of that by [Ken Puls](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/10/08/clean-whitespace-in-powerquery/), which adds the worksheet function TRIM feature of replacing sequential "chars" within the string with only a single one.